# Infopath : Textbox Limiting characters

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-rules

I have never created/worked on Infopath 2010 . I want to create a infopath form with 3 textbox . I should be able to validate the 1st textbox ,

```
1.if the characters are more than 65 then start filling text box(2) and 
2.If the characters exceed 115 then fill the 3rd text box.
3.If the characters are less than 65 in textbox1 ,fill the textbox2 & textbox3 with same data as tb1.
```

Comment: you can refer this for help http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/infopath-help/limit-characters-in-a-text-box-HA001116966.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion but this is a few dirty:)
You must add a number field foreach text fields. so you must add role into text1 when this field change (select text1 in home menu click add role then click this field change and set value) in the set value field insert this text1 number field and for value type this string-length(text1) and so for other text fields do this!
Now in the form design put all text field near together in one cell!
then add role validation to the text fields and in condition set for example when number1 field is less than 65 hide the text2 and text 3 and so you can fill 3 text or more in this condition!
**Hope this is usefull**